# RestDocumentation class is deprecated, what should I use instead?

Tags: java, spring, spring-restdocs

[The documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-restdocs/docs/current-SNAPSHOT/api/org/springframework/restdocs/RestDocumentation.html) for `org.springframework.restdocs.RestDocumentation` states that it is deprecated.

I am trying to use the class in a JUnit test like this:

```
@Rule
public RestDocumentation restDocumentation = new RestDocumentation("target/generated-snippets");
```

What class should I be using instead?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try `JUnitRestDocumentation restDocumentation = new JUnitRestDocumentation("target/generated-snippets")`